# Scala mutable collection with sorting on insert

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm looking for a Scala mutable sequential collection that sorts elements on insert. I.e. after I've finished inserting the elements, the resulting collection is sorted. It seems this thing doesn't exist, but maybe I'm missing something? It probably wouldn't be so hard to implement, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

**EDIT**: Set semantics are not suitable, since elements could be repeated.

**EDIT**: I'm looking for Scala collection, not Java one. This question is not about how to achieve such behavior on JVM, but about existing Scala collection that does this. If such thing doesn't exist, I'll accept such answer.

Comment: You could use Java's TreeSet. It's iterable so I suppose it matches your criterion of being "sequential"?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `java.util.PriorityQueue`.

**Edit**

There is [`scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue). But only `dequeue` and `dequeueAll` method will maintain order.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue
val pq = new PriorityQueue()(Ordering[Int].reverse) //default is descending order
pq += 5
pq += 4
pq += 2
pq.enqueue    //2
pq.enqueueAll //Vector(4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you looking for mutable collection consider using java's TreeSet

Comment: Set semantics are not suitable, since elements could be repeated. I've updated the question.

Comment: Map of List or some other collection type then, or map of Int (occurrences count)